# Android webview zooming buttons

Tags: android

how can I prevent zoom controls in webview from disappearing after zooming in or out.

and these zoom controls always show up after sliding the webview i.e. zoom controls do not show up autmatically as soon as webview loads up.

I have tried this code.

```
webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);                                                                                                                                                                                                             
//getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings(); 
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true) ;
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
// findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01).;
 webview.invokeZoomPicker();
```

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is to implement a ZoomButtonsController.

```
class myClass implements ZoomButtonsController.OnZoomListener{

     public ZoomButtonsController zoomy;
     private WebView myWebView;

     public myClass(){
      zoomy = new ZoomButtonsController(this);
      zoomy.setOnZoomListener(this);
      zoomy.setZoomSpeed(500);
      zoomy.setAutoDismiss(false);
     }

    @Override
    public void onZoom(boolean zoomIn) {
        if(zoomIn){
            myWebView.zoomIn();
        }else{
            myWEbView.zoomOut();
        }
    }

    public void toggleZoom(){
       if(!zoomy.isVisible()){
          zoomy.setVisible(true);
       }else{
          zoomy.setVisible(false);
       }
    }

}
```

Hope this gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: justin thanks for replying. i will try 2 implement this. +1 for good explanation...

Comment: @mice Android applications are written in Java.

Comment: Thanks for kind explanation :) I just don't recognize "function" keyword in Java. Even Java compiler does not.

Comment: @mice Oh wow! Thanks for the catch. I do so much work in both Java and PHP, I sometimes get my thoughts crossed. Answer edited to reflect the correction.